# Android - ScrollView is not scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview

i'm having problem with scrollview. It isn't working.

I read somewhere that you should only have one child view in ScrollView and maybe that's the problem, but i need a few horizontal lines. And i'm representing them in one view. You can see in my code two views inside RelativeLayout which is inside ScrollView.

**UPDATE:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/url"
        >

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2000dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

             <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/slika"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/slika"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/slika"
                android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
                android:text="Orginalni naslov:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/naslov"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/slika"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/naslov"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/naslov"
                android:layout_below="@+id/naslov"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:text="Početak prikazivanja filma:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/datum_prikazivanja_filma"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/datum_prikazivanja_filma"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/datum_prikazivanja_filma"
                android:layout_below="@+id/datum_prikazivanja_filma"
                />

            <View
                 android:id="@+id/view"
                 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
                 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="1dp"
                 android:background="#c0c0c0"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"/>

            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/Button1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view"/>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/ime1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Button1"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button1"
                android:text="Ime"/>

            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view"/>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/ime2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button2"
                android:text="Ime"/>

            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/Button3"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view"/>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/ime3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Button3"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button3"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button3"
                android:text="Ime"/>

            <View
                 android:id="@+id/view2"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="1dp"
                 android:background="#c0c0c0"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/ime3"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:text="Opis filma:"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>              
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are correct that `ScrollView` should only have one child, in your case that is your `RelativeLayout`, so thats not your issue. Please update your question to provide more information about what isn't working correctly.

Comment: ScrollView isn't scrolling. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `ScrollView` height is set to `fill_parent`. First off, you should always use `match_parent`. Second, your scroll view will never scroll unless it is actually **larger** than its parent view.

So try setting the height of your `ScrollView` to `WRAP_CONTENT` that way it can expand to the full size of your `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

> I read somewhere that you should only have one child view in `ScrollView`

Yes.

`ScrollView` should always hold one child and that's exactly what you're doing.

### Understanding the problem

Take a look at the child of your `ScrollView`, it's your `RelativeLayout`.

At it's very beginning, you define it to have a `width` that matche's it's parent (`ScrollView`) and a `height` large enough to `wrap_content`:

```
   <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </RelativeLayout>
```

How do you expect to scroll anything if it configured to be the same size as your `ScrollView`?

### Solution

You need to use something like this instead:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2000dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView114"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="127dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView117"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView114"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="268dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView118"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView117"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1200dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Okay, i have changed my xml file as you said, but now i'm getting some weird order of views. For example image is not showing at all.

Comment: You're using volley's `NetworkImageView`. Maybe there's something wrong going there. Try creating a simple List with simple objects first (not from volley), then you can identify better your problem.

Comment: Nothing is wrong. I could see it when i couldn't scroll down. Image is at the top. And also textView which should be right below the image also at the top is now at bottom.

Comment: I have edited my question. Still i'm not getting good view. Image isn't showing.

Comment: Create a single activity and set it's contentView to the layout I just provided you. Then, adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I'm getting this in xml file: This ScrollView layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless What should i do?